# How to change folder path in DerivedData?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, continuous-integration, parallel-builds

I have the following scenario:

whenever i do a build, i know that my products and build artifacts get generated in a folder like: `/Users/david/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-foobar123`. Unfortunately, i'd like to multiple `xctool build` for different targets, with different code, in parallel.

Is it safe to assume that `MyProject-foobar123` is always going to be the output folder for each of these builds?

If so, how can i change it so that even though i'm building the same project (with different code each time in parallel), that i am able to build into different folders?

the reason i want to know is because i try to `rm -rvf /Users/david/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-foobar123` as well as `xctool clean` before i start another build (but obviously this will run into problem when i parallelize the build)